# What is a "short texture" in the context of baking?

Tags: word-meaning

I stumbled upon an [answer on the cooking stack exchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/118132) mentioning the term "shorter texture":

> It will give you a coconuty taste and a **shorter texture** than cream,
> but this can happen with other substitute fats too.

What does it mean in that context? My best guess is "crumbly" like shortbread, the Scottish pastry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In baking, 'short' usually means 'having a high proportion of fat to flour', which gives a more crumbly or flaky texture to bread, pastry, cakes, etc. In the opinion of the poster on the Seasoned Advice SE, if coconut milk is used instead of cream in making milk bread, then the bread will be more crumbly or flaky. A substance containing fat added to a recipe for this purpose is sometimes called 'shortening', and the recipe is said to be 'shortened'

[What does 'short' mean in a recipe?](https://www.thekitchn.com/good-question-what-does-short-50169)

[Shortening (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortening#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20shortening,used%20to%20shorten%20baked%20goods)

Comment: Thank you! I also found this [article from the Chicago Tribune about shortcakes](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-2007-07-18-0707160458-story.html) that claims that "short" is an English term from the 16th century meaning "something made crisp with the addition of fat".